# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 TwiterKit

Tags: ios, cocoapods, twitterkit

For some reason twitterkit is in my project. I did not add it but I guess its part of another pod I have added. The issue im having is that it is giving me 43 errors.

It begins:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_TWTRCoreOAuthSigningOAuthEchoHeaders", referenced from:
      -[TWTROAuthSigning OAuthEchoHeadersForRequestMethod:URLString:parameters:error:] in TwitterKit(TWTROAuthSigning.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTRScribeService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TwitterKit(Twitter.o)
  "_TWTRTwitterAuthenticatePath", referenced from:
      -[TWTRWebAuthenticationViewController initWithAuthenticationToken:authConfig:APIServiceConfig:forceLogin:] in TwitterKit(TWTRWebAuthenticationViewController.o)
```

...

```
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**How can I fix this?**

My pods:

```
    pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'FirebaseUI'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 4.9'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Nuke', '~> 7.0'
```

Before adding Nuke, there was no issue.

### Update:

```
    pod 'SDWebImage' Seems to be the pod causing the issue: after remoiving it the errors were gone
```

**What should I do?**

### Update 2:

After reinstalling SDWebImage the errors are still gone. I do not know what caused the errors.

Comment: I've checked Nuke's podspec and source code. https://github.com/kean/Nuke It doesn't use TwitterKit. I think, the source of the problem is not in Nuke. Let's try to figure it out.

Comment: @AndreiKonstantinov It seems that I found the culpret check update

Comment: @AndreiKonstantinov well thats strange, becasue as soon as I commented out sdwebImage in my podfile and removed it in terminal all errors were gone. This was not the case for other pods I removed. And yes the errors are pasted directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problems with Cocoapods itself and not the specific pod. It happens.

- Close Xcode
- Execute `pod install` in terminal
- Clean project via Build -> Clean menu item
- Build project again
- If problem persist update cocoapods and repeat previous process